# Numpy: как перевернуть массив по оси

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Есть массив индексы которого идут слева направо, нужно чтоб они шли сверху вниз (тд я хочу потом добавить этот столбец в другому массиву)

Вот как у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот должно быть как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Транспонирование матрицы `arr2`: `arr2.T`. Альтернатива - функция [`numpy.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

Comment: Может быть вы уже начнете учебники читать? а то, судя по вашим вопросам, создается впечатление, что мы за вас лабораторную работу делаем.

Comment: На самом деле это и есть части небольшого проекта для учебы и так как преподаватель делает все на пайтоне, то получается большинство с группы тоже делают на пайтоне, включая меня.
Я не знаком с numpy и другими библиотеками пайтона, но смог бы сделать это все с циклами и простыми операциями, но делалось бы оно чудовищно долго, я обычно и делаю его циклами, а потом спрашиваю как оптимизировать и стараюсь примеры кода кидать та и кажется вы мне совсем нигде не помогли, ото только и можете критиковать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примеры:

для 1D матрицы (вектора):

```
In [109]: a = np.array([1,2,3])

In [110]: a
Out[110]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [111]: a.reshape(-1, 1)
Out[111]:
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

для 2D матрицы:

```
In [112]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)

In [113]: a
Out[113]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])

In [114]: a.T
Out[114]:
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])

In [115]: a.ravel().reshape(-1, 1)
Out[115]:
array([[ 0],
       [ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [ 5],
       [ 6],
       [ 7],
       [ 8],
       [ 9],
       [10],
       [11]])
```